# Upgrading Jenkins (LITS)

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade

I am current running version is 2.7.4 of Jenkins. However can I upgrade directly to 2.32.x or do I have to go through 2.19.x? The documentation does not specify that: https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/

Comment: You can upgrade directly; you should just take note of all of the items in that documentation between your current version and the version you want to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are on 2.x Jenkins, you can upgrade to latest 2.  But if this is important (which I'm guessing it is since you asked online before just trying it), backup your JENKINS_HOME first. Even though I trust this upgrade, we prepare rollback procedures for anything like this. For us we have a drive for the OS, and a drive for Jenkins data, which makes cloud/local backups/rollbacks easy.

Comment: Oh, great news thanks a lot. I usually perform a snapshot of the VM running Jenkins before a upgrade.